# Override delete method of custom object

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

we have an custom object in our instance that effectively is a junction object. Right now, if a relationship is removed, the record in the junction object is deleted.

We want to change this behavior to such that the junction object is marked as deleted, but not physically deleted (please understand that I cannot go into details of why, there are good business reasons to do so). Since we have multiple clients accessing our instance through SOAP and REST APIs I would like to implement a solution whereby I override the standard delete functionality of the custom object to just check a custom field is_deleted, instead of deleting the record.

Is this possible?

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can't just put an on-delete trigger on the object?

If you can, then just add the trigger code to update the field, and then attach an error to the record being deleted (so the deletion doesn't go through). There are plenty of examples in the official docs for how to do this.

Remember to keep everything bulkified (process all the records being deleted at once, from a list)...

On a side note, the deleted records in SalesForce are kept in the Recycle Bin on the org for 15 days after deletion. So you can also select them from the object, by using the SELECT... ALL ROWS query form.

Comment: I will try the on - delete trigger and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can really override delete action. You could override a button (with a Visualforce page) but that won't help you in any way if delete is fired from API.

I suspect you want to pretend to API (SOAP, REST etc) users that record was deleted while in reality retaining it somewhere? Smells like some shady business practice to be honest but whatever, let's assume it really is legit... For sure you can't suddenly throw errors at the operation because your end users will notice.

I think I'd go with a hidden 1-to-1 matching "shadow" object and sync each action to it. You'd need a trigger on insert/update/delete/undelete of your junction that would replicate the action (difference being this custom "soft delete" flag). This has lots of concerns like storage usage but well.

One thing that comes to mind is that (if I recall correctly) the triggers on junction object don't fire if you delete one of masters. So if it's a real junction object (you wrote "acts like") you'd have to deal with this scenario too and put logic into master objects' triggers.

If it's not a real junction object (i.e. it has `OwnerId` field visible) and your sharing rules permit - maybe you could transfer the ownership of record to some special user/queue outside of roles hierarchy so it becomes invisible... But I doubt it'll work, in the end the delete should appear to complete succesfully, right? Maybe in combination with some `@future` that'd immediately undelete them & transfer... Still - messy!

Comment: I do not want to hide records. It is about setting the deleted flag when a record when a delete action is triggered and prevent the record from being deleted. Pulling data, people would still need to account for the deleted flag, but that is marginal.

Comment: You'd have to throw exception or use `addError()` method to block the delete operation. This will stop the transaction I think (I doubt you'll be able to update them in same trigger). Read http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm carefully. I think you'll have to write a `before delete` that sets your flag, allows the operation to carry (no addError etc) and contains @future to immediately undelete them...